# SQL Check for multiple matching columns

Tags: sql, oracle, select

If I have a table Q with columns: IDNUMBER, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;

Each of the letter columns contain numbers but are nullable. Assume there are thousands of rows and I want to find all of the rows that Do Not have matching data for each IDNUMBER (A==B==C==D==E==F==G==H). However, I want to completely ignore null values.

The table could look like this (n means null):

```
IDNUMBER |  A |  B  | C  | D |  E |  F |  G 
---------+----+-----+----+---+----+----+----
  100    |  6 |  6  | 6  | 6 |  6 |  6 |  6 
  101    |  n |  n  | n  | n |  5 |  5 |  5
  102    |  3 |  3  | 3  | 4 |  3 |  3 |  3 
  103    |  3 |  n  | 5  | n |  5 |  n |  5
```

I would want to return the rows with IDNUMBERs 102 and 103 because their NON-NULL values do not match. I do not want to return the rows with IDNUMBERs 100 and 101 because their NON-NULL values match.

Can someone provide a SELECT statement that would work for this?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer 4.02.15.21

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, the easiest way would seem to be:

```
select q.*
from q
where greatest(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) <> least(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
```

Alas, this doesn't work because of `NULL` values.  This can make it challenging.  Here is an approach:

```
select q.*
from q
where greatest(coalesce(a, b, c, d, e, f, g),
               coalesce(b, c, d, e, f, g, a),
               coalesce(c, d, e, f, g, a, b),
               coalesce(d, e, f, g, a, b, c),
               coalesce(e, f, g, a, b, c, d),
               coalesce(f, g, a, b, c, d, e),
               coalesce(g, a, b, c, d, e, f)
              ) <>
      least(coalesce(a, b, c, d, e, f, g),
            coalesce(b, c, d, e, f, g, a),
            coalesce(c, d, e, f, g, a, b),
            coalesce(d, e, f, g, a, b, c),
            coalesce(e, f, g, a, b, c, d),
            coalesce(f, g, a, b, c, d, e),
            coalesce(g, a, b, c, d, e, f)
           ) ;
```

This compares each value, putting in some non-NULL value if available in the case of `NULL`.  You don't say what to do if all values are `NULL`.  In that case, nothing will be returned with this expression.

Comment: thank you, interesting idea; I used MAX and MIN functions in place of greatest and least but I'm getting the "group function is not allowed here" error for the line with MAX. I basically have:

SELECT * FROM
[subquery]
WHERE MAX(...) <> MIN(...)

any ideas?

Comment: @TJE97 . . . You can't use `max()` and `min()` in this context, because your data is denormalized.  Normalizing the rows and using aggregation functions would be another approach.

Comment: perhaps I don't understand what you've written then... what are greatest() and least()?

Comment: ah nevermind I did not realize that they are valid functions of their own -- my editor did not highlight them as keywords